# API Routes on Next.JS with Apollo-Server : why does using a basePath cause error?

Tags: graphql, next.js, apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server

I'm using [API Routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction) on a Next.JS app with Apollo-Server, to create a GraphQL API wrapper around a REST endpoint. But I'm running into an issue if the project has a [bathPath](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/basepath).

I've been following [this example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/api-routes-graphql), and a [video tutorial on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y34ym0-KZ8A&t=1461s).
I've replicated my issue by using the [repo](https://github.com/leighhalliday/apollo-nextjs) from that tutorial. Upon running that code `$ yarn dev`, and navigating to http://localhost:3000/api/graphql the GraphQl playground shows up, and works as expected.

However if I add a basepath to the project then the graphQl playground still shows up fine at http://localhost:300/basepath/api/graphql but it gives me the error of "Server cannot be reached" and shows a 404 error in the network tab on the dev tools.

To add the base path I created a **next.config.js** and added

```
module.exports = {
   basePath: '/basepath'
}
```

In **pages/api/graphql.ts** I updated the path from `/api/graphql` to `/basepath/api/graphql`

```
import { ApolloServer } from "apollo-server-micro";
import { schema } from "src/schema";

const server = new ApolloServer({ schema });
const handler = server.createHandler({ path: "/somewhere/api/graphql" });

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};

export default handler;
```

In **src/apollo.ts** I updated the HttpLink uri from `/api/graphql` to `/basepath/api/graphql`

```
import {
  ApolloClient,
  InMemoryCache,
  NormalizedCacheObject,
} from "@apollo/client";
import { useMemo } from "react";

let apolloClient: ApolloClient<NormalizedCacheObject>;

function createIsomorphicLink() {
  if (typeof window === "undefined") {
    // server
    const { SchemaLink } = require("@apollo/client/link/schema");
    const { schema } = require("./schema");
    return new SchemaLink({ schema });
  } else {
    // client
    const { HttpLink } = require("@apollo/client/link/http");
    return new HttpLink({ uri: "/bathpath/api/graphql" });
  }
}

function createApolloClient() {
  return new ApolloClient({
    ssrMode: typeof window === "undefined",
    link: createIsomorphicLink(),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  });
}

export function initializeApollo(initialState = null) {
  const _apolloClient = apolloClient ?? createApolloClient();

  if (initialState) {
    _apolloClient.cache.restore(initialState);
  }

  if (typeof window === "undefined") return _apolloClient;
  apolloClient = apolloClient ?? _apolloClient;

  return apolloClient;
}

export function useApollo(initialState) {
  const store = useMemo(() => initializeApollo(initialState), [initialState]);
  return store;
}
```

Any ideas why adding a basepath would break this setup? and what I'd need to do to fix it?

This is my first time posting on stack overflow, so I hope my description is good enough, please do ask if I've missed anything and thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: I don't know if this is still an issue for you, but I see a misspelling:
`return new HttpLink({ uri: "/bathpath/api/graphql" });`
Should be `basepath` and not `bathpath`?